# add item to list in a functional style

Tags: python-3.x

is there a function in python (or some library) that allows me to add items to a list that returns a list?

preferably a new list.

so an imperative style would be

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
thislist.append("orange")
print(thislist)
```

I'd like to go

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
newlist = thislist.cons("orange")
print(newlist)
```

I can obviously write such a thing, but this would seem to be (for someone from a functional background) a pretty basic tool in the toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `+`. Put orange in a new list, then add them together:

```py
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
newlist = thislist + ["orange"]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd: Note that your imperative-style example mutates the original list while this answer returns a new one. That may be acceptable to you, but it's worth pointing out the semantic difference.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's what functional means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I would generally recommend @Soren's answer because it is more readable and "pythonic", but worth mentioning that there is another option that can occasionally be useful:

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
newlist = [*thislist, "orange"]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: interesting, i have come across this * syntax